# How to get data(coordinates) from a text file and put it to a Vector3 array in C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

here is my data which is in a text file. These data are coordinates.

(55, 297)(300, 297)(55, 297)(55, 52)

I read these data points by the bellow code,

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {


            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\Users\\UVINDU\\Desktop\\Data.txt"))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)

               {
                   string splits = line.TrimStart('[');
                   string[] split = line.Split(')');


                   string a = split[0], b = split[1], c = split[2], d = split[3];

                   a = a.Trim(new Char[] { '[', '(' });
                   Console.WriteLine(a);

                   b = b.Trim(new Char[] { ',', '(' });
                   Console.WriteLine(b);

                   c = c.Trim(new Char[] { ',', '(' });
                   Console.WriteLine(c);

                   d = d.Trim(new Char[] { ',', '(' });
                   Console.WriteLine(d);
                   Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

how can I add these values(a,b,c,d) to a Vector3 array?

Comment: Just get value string and parse it to int or float like: `int x = int.Parse(valueString);`

Comment: @JerrySwitalski change your comment to answer so that he can accept it

Comment: @JerrySwitalski I want to know how to add these values to a Vector3 array?

Comment: I think you are a bit confused as what you are doing. Your tag said Unity3D (I removed it) but what you show is a VS application. But then you want to store in a Vector3 array which could be a Unity thing. Are you or not using Unity and if yes, why is the code not about Unity?

Comment: @fafase I'm using unity3D and hope you are familiar with vector3 cause that how you pass the game object position values

Comment: Vector what...3?...nope, not ringing any bell. Just like your snippet does not ring any Unity bell. There is no main method in Unity that you can use without screwing the engine and no Tasks namespace either. What you show is a basic Visual Studio console application (it is even in the name!!). I see you added back the Unity3D tag...well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basicly you want a parse string to float:

```
string s = "55";
string s2 = "297";
string s3 = "0";
float x = float.Parse(s);
float y = float.Parse(s2);
float z = float.Parse(s3);
```

Then you want to create Vector3 object:

```
Vector3 v1 = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Vector3 v2 = new Vector3(x2, y2, z2);
Vector3 v3 = new Vector3(x3, y3, z3);
Vector3 v4 = new Vector3(x4, y4, z4);
```

And finally you want to add this vector to array:

```
Vector3[] vArr = new Vector3[4] {v1, v2, v3, v4};
```

But frankly speaking I am not sure what the values you showed represent, and why there is missing third value for z.

Comment: the third value is always 0. that's why i have removed it